# How do I create a string from a specific range in a List<> with .NET4.0 and C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know I can use

```
List<string> dogs = new List<string>();
dogs.Add("Lab");
dogs.Add("Boston Terrier");
dogs.Add("Mastiff");
dogs.Add("Finnish Spitz");
dogs.Add("Golden Retriever");
string dogCsv = string.Join(",", dogs.ToArray());
```

to put all the dogs into a CSV string. But I want to create a string with each dog on it's own line, AND only dogs 3 thru 5. Is this possible?

Comment: `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dogs.Skip(2))`

Comment: I'm sorry. I may want a range like between 2 and 4 also.

Comment: `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dogs.Skip(2).Take(2))`

Comment: Even if you didn't know LINQ, it's possible to do this with a for loop. Any reason you didn't try that?

Comment: It didn't occur to me because I was going off the above snippet as it was the closest thing i could find. But a for loop would work just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get dogs within a certain range, you can pass the starting index and the number of items to get to the `GetRange` method on a `List`.

So, for your example of dogs 3 through 5, you would do:

```
var rangeOfDogs = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dogs.GetRange(2, 3));
```

A possible downside of using `GetRange` is that it will throw an exception if you pass it invalid values (like a starting index that doesn't exist, or more items to get than exist after the starting index).

If you want something that will just **try** to get the items, and not fail if it can't get all that you're asking for, you can use `Skip` and `Take`:

```
var rangeOfDogs = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dogs.Skip(2).Take(3));
```

Neither of these will throw an exception if the number specified is out of range, they will just return nothing (or whatever is actually within the specified range).